# Unable to set wss:// when connect @microsoft/signalr in react native with .net core api

Tags: .net, reactjs, react-native, signalr

I using @microsoft/signalr in react native app to connect with basic example in docs.

```
useEffect(() => {
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl('https://e-mobile-shop.azurewebsites.net/signalr')
  .build();

connection.on('SendNofti', data => {
  console.log('s');
});
connection.start();  }, []);
```

But it's not work with errors " Unable to set wss://..":
[errors like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owDgU.png)

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: How are you mapping your hub on the server side? From your error, your hub name looks like: "signalr`1" which could lead to issues as it has the "backtick" character.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/chathub")
.build();

async function start() {
try {
    await connection.start();
    console.log("SignalR Connected.");
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    setTimeout(start, 5000);
}
};
  connection.onclose(start);
 // Start the connection.
start();
```